# No matching function call in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm getting the error of 'no matching function call' any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void redactDigits(string & s);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    redactDigits("hello");

    return 0;
}

void redactDigits(string & s){

double stringLength = 0;
string copyString; 

stringLength = s.size();

for (int i = 0; i < stringLength + 1; i++) {
    if (atoi(&s[i])) {
        copyString.append(&s[i]);
    }

    else {
        copyString.append("*");
    }


}

s = copyString;

cout << s; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `void` in your function declaration. Furthermore, you need to pass a `const` reference, to be able to bind to a temporary:

```
void redactDigits(const string & s);
^^^^              ^^^^^
```

Without the `const`, this call is illegal:

```
redactDigits("hello");
```

although some compilers have non-standard extensions that allow non-const references to bind to temporaries.

**Edit**: Since you are attempting to modify the input string inside your function, another solution is to either keep your original function signature and pass it an `std::string` instead of a null-terminated string literal, or just return an std::string:

```
std::string redactDigits(const std::string& s)
{
  ...
  return copyString;
}
```

then

```
std::string s = redactDigits("hello");
```

Comment: @user1681673 including the `const`?